# Why is InfiniteIterator not repeating an ArrayIterator?

Tags: php

Putting these [SPL iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) together this way:

```
$iterator = new LimitIterator(
    new InfiniteIterator(
        new ArrayIterator(range(1, 3))
    ),
    0,
    5
);

echo implode(', ', iterator_to_array($iterator));
```

I would expect to get this output: `1, 2, 3, 1, 2`.

After iterating the first time over the ArrayIterator (`1, 2, 3`), the InfiniteIterator should rewind the ArrayIterator and start from beginning, until the limit of the LimitIterator is reached (`1, 2, 3, 1, 2`).

But actually its output is `1, 2, 3`. Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your combination of iterators is working as expected. If you iterate it with foreach

```
foreach ($iterator as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

You'll get the expected output `12312`.

The problem is actually when you convert it back to an array with `iterator_to_array`.

You need to set the [second parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php#refsect1-function.iterator-to-array-parameters) (`$use_keys`) to `false` (the default is `true`), or it will overwrite the repeated keys.

```
echo implode(', ', iterator_to_array($iterator, false));
```

Comment: That makes absolutely sense. Thanks!